# Laravel order by related table

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, html-table

I have Product and Category models in my project. Product belongs to Category. Since Product has foreign key category_id, I could easily sort the output like so:

```
$products = Product::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->get();
```

But what I really wanted is to sort Products by Category name, so I tried:

```
$products = Product::with(['categories' => function($q){
            $q->orderBy('name', 'asc')->first();
        }]);
```

But that outputs nothing. As a test, I have returned `return Product::with('categories')->first();` and it outputs fine...

Here are the Eloquent relations.

**Product**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'price',
        'category_id',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**Category:**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Product');
    }
}
```

And the view part:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
                <tr>

                    <td>{!! $product->categories->name !!}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if(!empty($product->picture))
                            Yes
                        @else
                            No
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>{!! $product->name !!}</td>
                    <td>{!! $product->description !!}</td>
                    <td>{!! $product->price !!}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{ url('/product/'.$product->id.'/edit') }}">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil text-warning"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="" data-href="{{route('product.destroyMe', $product->id)}}"
                           data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-times text-danger"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I think this should work

```
// Get all the products
$products = \App\Product::all();

// Add Closure function to the sortBy method, to sort by the name of the category
$products->sortBy(function($product) { 
  return $product->categories()->name;
});
```

This should also working:

```
 $products = Product::with('categories')->get()
   ->sortBy(function($product) { 
       return $product->categories->name;
  })
```

Comment: That doesn't work. And has no logical sense. Product can have only one category. I have tested my relationships in Tinker, and they work as they should. Models shouldn't be the problem

Comment: This is grammar issue, if product have only one category, don't name it as plural like categories. It is confusing

Comment: I thought it was a convention thing?

Comment: It should not affect the result, but it just against the convention I think for one to many relationship

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Your answer almost does the trick...update it like so: $products = Product::with('categories')->get()->sortBy(function($product) {
            return $product->categories->name;
        });

Comment: @Norgul: Updated with yours. But I think it should be working. I have not removed it yet until I tested it. Please vote up if it is useful.

Comment: I have tested it, and it didn't work for me. Btw. you have a typo...when you return $product->categories, it should be without brackets

Comment: @geckob you are just sorting on collection(already retrived data from db)

Comment: @fico7489 Yes. It retrieve and sort

Answer (score 8):

You can use join(), try below code

```
$query = new Product; //new object
//$query = Product::where('id','!=',0);
$query = $query->join('categories', 'categories.id','=','products.categories.id');
$query = $query->select('categories.name as cat_name','products.*');
$query = $query->orderBy('cat_name','asc');
$record = $query->get();
```

Comment: Why new product? I need all existing products

Comment: Using new you can create new object of 'Product' class So if you can append some additional where clause, also you can replace first line with the second.

Comment: In case there are products that don't belong to any category, use `leftjoin` instead of `join`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, with some simple tweaks, like using left join instead of join, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply supply function to Eloquent eager loading where you can handle how the related table gets queried.

```
$product = Product::with(['categories' => function ($q) {
  $q->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])->find($productId);
```

Answer (score -2):

In laravel, you can't perform order by related table without manually joining related table what is really very awkward, but this can package can do this for you out of the box https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-eloquent-join